# VS 2022 WCF Service Application project template not working with Net TCP

Tags: c#, wcf

I'm trying to get the simplest WCF Service Application to work with net.tcp and it's not working. Using VS2022, if I create a new project and select the WCF Service Application Template, the new project opens with a Web.config file, Service1.svc file and a IService.svc.

The Web.config looks like this,

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>

  <appSettings>
    <add key="aspnet:UseTaskFriendlySynchronizationContext" value="true" />
  </appSettings>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.7.2" />
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.7.2"/>
  </system.web>
    <system.serviceModel>
        <behaviors>
            <serviceBehaviors>
                <behavior>
                    <!-- To avoid disclosing metadata information, set the values below to false before deployment -->
                    <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpsGetEnabled="true"/>
                    <!-- To receive exception details in faults for debugging purposes, set the value below to true.  Set to false before deployment to avoid disclosing exception information -->
                    <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false"/>
                </behavior>
            </serviceBehaviors>
        </behaviors>
        <protocolMapping>
            <add binding="basicHttpsBinding" scheme="https" />
        </protocolMapping>
        <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
    </system.serviceModel>
    <system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
    <directoryBrowse enabled="true"/>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

If I run this sample project it loads the WCF Test client and shows the service running with the BasicHttpBinding. Perfect.

If I change the binding in the config file from `<add binding="basicHttpsBinding" scheme="https" />` to `<add binding="wsHttpBinding" scheme="http" />` and run the project, the WCF Test Client shows the WSHttpBinding. Great! Now if I change the binding in the config file from `<add binding="wsHttpBinding" scheme="http" />` to `<add binding="netTcpBinding" scheme="net.tcp" />` and run the project, the WCF Test Client shows the service running with the BasicHttpBinding. THERE'S NOT EVEN A BasicHttpBinding BINDING IN THE CONFIG FILE!!!!! WHERE THE HELL IS IT GETTING THAT FROM? I've been trying for days to netTcpBinding to work and no matter I do, nothing works. I figured I'd try the simplest thing I could do, which was start with a fresh blank project and make the simplest change, and still no luck. What am I missing. I can find nearly no information on getting this work.

Answer (score 0):

First you have to understand the meaning of <[protocolMapping](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/configure-apps/file-schema/wcf/protocolmapping)>. The configuration in  shows the default protocol mapping in the machine.config file.

> You need to override this default mapping at the machine level by
> modifying the machine.config file. Alternatively, if you just want to
> override it application-wide, you can override this section in the
> application configuration file and change the mapping for the
> individual protocol schemes.

More generally, the HTTP system-provided bindings such as wsHttpBinding and basicHttpBinding are configured to turn things on by
default, whereas the netTcpBinding binding turns things off by default so that you have to opt-in to get support, for example, for one of the WS-* specifications.

You need to modify the configuration file, you can see how `<netTcpBinding>` is configured. If you host your service on IIS, you need IIS to have net.tcp enabled.
[netTcpBinding In WCF Service With IIS Hosting](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/nettcpbinding-in-wcf-service-with-iis-hosting/)

[nettcpbinding](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/configure-apps/file-schema/wcf/nettcpbinding)

[default-nettcpbinding](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/samples/default-nettcpbinding)

If you need simple projects to start with, I suggest you start with wcf's beginners tutorial.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/getting-started-tutorial